# Use Name for Key in a Map

Tags: apex

The below is a valid way to create a Map.

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> mapOpps = new Map <Id, Opportunity>();
```

I know that I can use String in place of ID. BUT could someone please explain to me why can't I use Name, as shown?

```
Map<Name, Opportunity> mapOpps = new Map <Name, Opportunity>();
```

Comment: Pro tip: naming conventions for maps: maps of Opportunities by Id should not be named `mapContacts`. I'd name it `opportunitiesById` - the `...by...` is the cue it is a map.

Answer (score 4):

The `Type` for this field is `String`. There is no `Type` called `Name`. Note also that the Id Map is the only built in constructor. For any other map, you will need to construct it empty then loop to populate. One more note, this field is not unique. If you have multiple records with the same name, it is arbitrary which one ends up in the map.

```
Map<String, MyObject> nameToRecord = new Map<String, MyObject>();
for (MyObject record : someCollection)
    nameToRecord.put(record.Name, record);
```

Comment: To clarify, when you use "Id" in the type declaration of a map, it is the type NOT the field. Salesforce provides a special constructor to convert a List<SObject> into a Map<Id, SObject>.

Comment: NB: It is possible to use a static initializer for a Map to avoid looped put if you have a defined number of entries to add. E.g. new Map<String, String> { 'key' => 'value' }.

Comment: There is a Name type, though. It's used for polymorphic "people" fields, like Owner. You're still correct in the solution, but you might want to correct the Name part.

Answer (score 1):

> why can't I use Name, as shown? `Map<Name, Opportunity>`

Because it’s **not a valid data type** for the **key**. Name is a field either text or auto number for any SObject and that only the following are valid data types for a [Map’s keys and values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm):

> Map keys and values can be of any data type—primitive types, collections, sObjects, user-defined types, and built-in Apex types.

Comment: Again, to clarify, Name is NOT a type, it is a field name.

Comment: Thank you all for advice! I understand now. Key has to be a data type, like those here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm

Comment: Name is a valid data type. It represents polymorphic "people" fields, such as Owner. Granted, it's not what the user needs, but you should be aware of this feature.

Comment: I wouldn’t really think it to be a data type though. It could still be a type polymorphic field but does not really categorize as data type in context of apex. The data type of Name itself will be either text or number.